# Как выпустить несколько лучей от одного объекта в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как я могу выпустить несколько лучей из одного объекта в Unity?

Я сделал, чтобы 4 луча уже выходили, но я сомневаюсь, что это нужно делать именно таким способом.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    Ray _ray_0 = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
    Ray _ray_1 = new Ray(transform.position, -transform.forward);
    Ray _ray_2 = new Ray(transform.position, transform.right);
    Ray _ray_3 = new Ray(transform.position, -transform.right);
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.forward*Delta_Range, Color.yellow);
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, -transform.forward*Delta_Range, Color.yellow);
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.right*Delta_Range, Color.yellow);
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, -transform.right*Delta_Range, Color.yellow);
}
```

Ведь если мне нужно будет сделать не 4, а 15 лучей, то, используя этот способ, придется прописывать все 15 лучей отдельно.

Мне кажется, что есть более красивый и простой способ сделать это?
Мне интересно разобраться, как сделать это именно с помощью лучей (Raycast).
[image: То что я уже получил]

Comment: Я думаю, единственный правильный способ сделать что-то одинаковое несколько раз -- это, очевидно, цикл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот код генерирует заданное количество лучей вокруг объекта с равными углами между ними:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteAlways] // Это нужно, чтобы можно было увидеть результат, не запуская игру
public class Character : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField, Min(1)] private int _countRays; // Кол-во лучей
    [SerializeField] private float _length; // Длина

    public void Update()
    {
        DrawRays();
    }

    private void DrawRays ()
    {
        float circumference = 2 * Mathf.PI;
        float angle = circumference / _countRays; // Высчитываем угол
        for (float currAngle = 0; currAngle < circumference; currAngle += angle)
        {
            Vector3 direction = new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(currAngle), 0, Mathf.Sin(currAngle)); // Расчитываем луч
            
            Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, direction * _length, Color.red);
        }
    }
}
```

Вместо `[SerializeField, Min(1)]`, что задает минимальное количество лучей -- 1, можно написать `[SerializeField, Range(X, Y)]`. Так вы четко ограничите количество лучей: от X до Y, а переменная в инспекторе превратится в удобный ползунок.

Comment: И вообще к переменной `_length` тоже можно прибавить аттрибут Min(0), чтобы длина не могла быть отрицательной (хотя даже в таком случае ошибок не будет)